# placeholder for postgresql box type, using DBI/DBD::PG

Tags: perl, postgresql, placeholder, dbi

I am trying to use placeholders to insert geometric type into a postgresql database.

I tried the two codes below :

```
my $sth = ($dbh)->prepare("INSERT INTO lrad.matable(zone) VALUES (BOX'((?,?),(?,?))');"); 
$sth->execute(0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6);
```

which results in `DBD::Pg::st execute failed: called with 4 bind variables when 0 are needed`

```
my $sth = ($dbh)->prepare("INSERT INTO lrad.matable(zone) VALUES (((?,?),(?,?)));"); 
$sth->execute(0.5,0.7,0.4,0.6);
```

which results in `column "zone" is of type box but expression is of type record
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Any idea of a way to fix it ? or will i be force to build my box without placeholders ?

Comment: Are you sure the `BOX'((?,?),(?,?))'` is correct? Have you tried it without the quotes (`'`) as `BOX((?,?),(?,?))`?

Comment: yes the quotes are necessary, or it dies *invalid input syntax for type box: "BOX((0.5,0.7),(0.4,0.6))"* the quotes are the correct syntax to insert boxtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use functions rather than casts to build up the box:

```
INSERT INTO lrad.matable(zone) VALUES (box(point(?,?),point(?,?)))
```

You could also build up the string "(0.5,0.7),(0.4,0.6)" in perl, and pass that string in to a single ? placeholder:

```
    INSERT INTO lrad.matable(zone) VALUES (?::box)
```